# GET boolean response through restangular

Tags: angularjs

I have created a rest service using Jersey. The service allows user to check if the username is already available or has been used by someone.

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/user/checkUname/uname
```

This returns true or false and it works fine.

Now in my UI I am trying to use the Restangular in Angularjs where my code is as follow

```
var userBaseUrl = Restangular.all('user');

var valid = userBaseUrl.one('checkUname',uname).get();
```

But 'valid' does not have a boolean value.

All the executions are working proper as I see in the debugging.

How do I access a boolean response through Restangular ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do this:

```
Restangular.all('user').one('checkUname', uname).get().then(
  function (valid) {
    //check here
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks it is working. Probably it is doing a lazy load which was misleading me.

Comment: it is async so the returned value should be a promise, so You can access to the data by the success callback